# Select between two dates in European Format

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, date, between

The following query doesn't return any results when I try to select records between February and March.

Here is the query that I'm using :

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM data WHERE  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),data,105) BETWEEN  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "',105) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),'"+dateTimePicker3.Text+"',105)", conn);
```

- `data` is type VARCHAR(50) and i want to convert it to dd-MM-yyyy format

Comment: Do not compare dates converted into `VARCHAR`, convert both dates to `DATETIME` before comparing.

Comment: Data column is VARCHAR(50)

Comment: @user2989408 i cant unrestand u , can u type the querry , what do you mean don convert both dates ?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky its dd-mm-yyyy (24-2-2013)

Comment: @user2989408 i already did , if u can see in the querry CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),data,105)

PLS help someone i need the whole querry

Comment: Show us some sample data and also you are converting the dates into `VARCHAR`, to compare you need to convert them into dates.

Comment: Read @Aaron-Bertrand [blog about not using between](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries) - you should **not** store dates as strings - you're just asking for trouble that way. Use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` datatypes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL should be something like

```
 SELECT * FROM data 
 WHERE  CONVERT(datetime, data, 105)  >= CONVERT(datetime, '01-01-2014', 105) 
     AND  CONVERT(datetime, data, 105) <= CONVERT(datetime, '01-31-2014', 105)
```

Comment: Still doenst works, when i want to select data from 01-02-2014 to 01-03-2013 it shows nothing :(

Comment: Brother, thank u very much it works now i think i will test it more, u just forgot to change (VARCHAR(50),'"+datetimepicker3.text+"',105) to (datetime, '" + dateTimePicker3.Text + "', 105)

Comment: Glad it worked. I was just showing the SQL you can convert it into C# accordingly.

Comment: @user3334406 I highly recommend you use a parametarized query also.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `date` value from `DatePicker` Once you convert everything to `Date` SQL will not have problem of comparing mm-dd-yyyy to dd-mm-yyyy

```
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,MyStringDate,105) >= dateTimePicker1.Value.Date
AND CONVERT(DATE,MyStringDate,105) <= dateTimePicker.Value.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing too many conversions.  SQL will have a hard time determining `BETWEEN` on `VARCHAR` types.

Instead convert things to `DATE` or `DATETIME` (depending on your SQL Server Version and type)

Also you should use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection.

Something like this would work well:

```
using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter())
{
    da.SelectCommand.CommandText = 
         "SELECT * FROM data WHERE CONVERT(datetime, data, 105) >= @Date1 AND CONVERT(datetime, data, 105) <= @Date2";
    //Use the DateTimePicker's Value property here, not the Text Property
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date1", dateTimePicker1.Value);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date2", dateTimePicker3.Value);
    da.Fill(yourDataTable); //Or whatever you're doing
}
```